# I cannot install Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS because it cannot mount the CD drive

Tags: 12.04, installation, cd-drive

I tried installing Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, and it doesn't work. Well, it does, until the third step, in which it says it cannot mount the CD-ROM drive and tells me to insert the installation disk.

I am using a USB to install. If I put in the DVD into the drive and I try to boot it the computer just boots to Ubuntu (Ubuntu Desktop). I have a spare drive if this one is faulty, but I don't want to need to install it. I am also using the 64-bit version.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you changed the BIOS boot order?

Comment: Found the problem. Apparently, Ubuntu 12.04 needs a SATA connection to the CD Drive. I got my spare, which HAD a SATA connection. It worked like a charm. My server is a few (more like 6) years old. That probably was why.

Comment: Press <kbd>F6</kbd> (More Options) at the Installation home screen and disable the option "use acpi = on". Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, and continue with installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently, Ubuntu 12.04 needs a SATA connection to the CD Drive. I got my spare, which HAD a SATA connection. It worked like a charm. My server is a few (more like 6) years old. That probably was why.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem: installation DVD booted but during the installation it 'could not mount the CD-ROM'.   Cured by moving the jumper on the IDE DVD from the CSEL position (left hand pins) to the Master position (right hand pins).